# How much trouble can the use of Singleton class as Model cause?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, programming-practices, code-quality, organization

In my latest WPF applications I've been using a Singleton class, that I call Model, to contain all my application's logic, such as file reading, information handling, etc..

In the WPF Views or Windows I just call the methods that I need, when I need them: `Model.Instance.GetProducts(string category);`

Besides having always the same instance, I find this convenient because I can call any method that I want in any window, and I can define the Model in App.xaml to be a StaticResource and then do the bindings that I need. For example, set the Binding of a DataGrid to an ObservableCollection present in the Model.

What do you think of this approach? A few years ago at college, when working with Windows Forms we used to work with the MVC pattern, where the controller would contain some events that called methods from the Model, and those events would later be invoked by the Views.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29

Comment: What is your unit-testing strategy?

Comment: recommended reading: **[What is the problem with “Pros and Cons”?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6758/31260)**

Comment: @gnat any suggestion on how to improve my question?

Comment: @Den I'm trying to figure out one :/

Comment: did you check meta guidance referred in prior comment? "Many of the questions that have been asked in the 'pros and cons' format... can fairly easily be rewritten in a way that..." etc

Comment: Not much, possibly just [a withdrawal of $100 from your credit card every time your unit test runs](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/) (example).

Comment: Nice article. My singleton is now "erased" from every code file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[God object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) [is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560217/is-a-class-that-manages-multiple-classes-a-god-object) [of the worst](https://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2009/05/28/anti-patterns-and-worst-practices-monster-objects/) "designs" you can create. Please, put some effort into separating different concerns. Your future self will thank you.

Comment: I was expecting that answer. The hard part how to fix it.

Comment: @cap7 Refactor it. Slowly and carefully.

Comment: I've already started. For example, I've a class that only handles the database querying. Since that class has no state and is just a series of related methods that, when given an input, will give you an output, it's is defined as static and once the methods are finished I just forget them. I don't know if that is the best option.